# SplitViewController - can one change the z-order of rootview and detailview?

Tags: ios4, ipad

In an iPad splitview app I am animating changes to the subview of the detailview by moving the views from left to right.

If the app starts in Landscape then when a view is animated to the left it goes underneath the rootview or left view.  However if the iPad is rotated to Portrait and then back to Landscape then when a subview moves left it is over the top of the rootview.

What options do I have to either bring the rootview to the front or send the subviews of the detailview side backwards?

Comment: Sometimes if you ask a question you then work out the answer and I have.

I did not think bringtofront would work but it does.

    [_splitViewController.view bringSubviewToFront:[[_splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] view]];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes if you ask a question you then work out the answer and I have. I did not think bringtofront would work but it does.

[_splitViewController.view bringSubviewToFront:[[_splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] view]];

(added once I could answer my own question)